# Missing comments either from the comment FQL Table or through the Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-comments

An album I posted on Facebook has 41 comments, the last comment I see when browsing with my browser has ID [10150778810571046](https://www.facebook.com/browse/likes/?id=10150778810571046) (I liked it, this is the like URL) but this comment doesn't appear when using the FQL comment table... !

A FQL call using "SELECT comments FROM stream WHERE post_id='689541045_10150777768986046'" returns 40 as a comment count, and doesn't return the last comment I liked in the comment_list.

A FQL call to fetch the regular newsfeed and returning the last 25 stories returns 41 has a comment count, and doesn't return anything in the comment_list.

[Both FQL call results are online in a gist](https://gist.github.com/f76a062ec713bfb91c12).

Has anyone had similar issues?

Comment: have you tried to do fql to get the content of this last comment?

Comment: @ThreeDev: yes, but you can't do it as comment.id isn't indexable. [As explained here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/). I tried to fetch all comments for the post_id and it doesn't return the comment I'm looking for. I tried with the graph API and it only returns 'false'.

Comment: I filled up a bug report at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/264743653623137 as it seems to be a facebook bug.